# Update resource file variable in new resource file

Tags: robotframework

Here is the problem context: I have two robot files: `file1.robot` and `file2.robot`.

`file1.robot`

Defines in the `*** Variables ***` section a list:
`@{real}` with some values.

Now I have a second file: `file2.robot` which import the `file1.robot` with the instruction:

`Resource            ./file1.robot`

When I try to update the real list in the `file2.robot` in the variables section using the command:

`${real}=    Append To List     ${real}    connectModule`

I get the messages:
Recursive variable definition.
and
Variable '${real}' not found.
Any idea how I could do it?
Sincerely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done exactly as you have described it. It is difficult to say where you have mistake from what you have shown us, keyword *Append To List* has no return value that however should not result in your error. But below code should work

**test.robot**

```
Library    Collections
Resource    ${CURDIR}/unnecessary.resource



*** Test Cases ***   
test
    Collections.Append To List    ${test_list}    new    values
    Log    ${test_list}
```

**useful.resource**

```
*** Variables ***
@{test_list}    some    values
```

**unnecessary.resource**

```
*** Settings ***
Resource          ${CURDIR}/useful.resource
```

I have all 3 files in the same folder

Comment: Thank you for this first answer.
I was wondering if the list element addition could take place somehow in the `unnecessary.resource` file *** Variables *** section?

Comment: you mean append to the list in *unnecessary.resource*? I dont think that that is possible.